# Error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I searched through some Qs but i couldn't find an answer.

I wanted overload `operator<<` but it doesn't work for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

class Foo
{
public:
    std::tuple<int, float> tp;
    Foo(int _a, float _b)
    {
         std::get<0>(tp)=_a;
         std::get<1>(tp) =_b;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & strm, const std::tuple<int, float> &tp)
    {
         strm << "[ "<<std::get<1>(tp)<<", "<<std::get<0>(tp)<<"]"<<"\n";
         return strm;
    }
};

int main () 
{

  Foo a(1, 3.0f);
  std::cout<<a;
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
     std::cout<<a;
                ^
```

**Update**
Solved, Thanks @juanchopanza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to call `std::cout<<a;`, you need to overload an output stream operator that has a `Foo` as second parameter. For example:

```
friend
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const Foo& foo) 
{
  return strm << "[ " << std::get<1>(foo.tp) << ", "
              << std::get<0>(foo.tp) << "]" << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i can't believe i made this mistake after months of studying :'(